# How can I run an arbitrary command when ping completes?

Tags: networking, ping

How can I construct a command to ping a host every minute or something, then run a command when it doesn't time out (when the pinged host comes online)?

Basically I want the following pseudocode:

```
bool ping = pingHost();
while (ping = false) {
    //try again
    ping = pingHost();
}
runCommand("whatever");
```

Preferably, answers would include instructions for UNIX-like systems (using bash, etc) as well as Windows systems (cmd, PowerShell or Cygwin all work).

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried? Did you try a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ping+until+reply) for this?

Comment: @CharlieRB ah, I didn't think of that. I just searched for "run command on ping success" or something, which returned much less useful results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all please let me point out that you would probably want to use a more complete monitoring software like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) for this.

For the basic scripting solution, on Linux I would use Bash for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 1 yourhost.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    your_command
fi
```

Windows is quite similar actually. Put this into a `.bat` file:

```
ping -n 1 yourhost.com
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    your_command
)
```

**Explanation:** the ping command returns an exit code on both operating systems. On Linux (Bash) you have the `$?` variable to get this exit code, on Windows it's `%errorlevel%`. When the ping is successful, the exit code on both operating systems is 0, otherwise it's 1. This value can be used to run your command conditionally.

**Adding the loop:**

On Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=1
while [ $result -neq 0 ]; do
    ping -c 1 yourhost.com
    result=$?
done
```

On Windows the same would be:

```
:loop
ping -n 1 yourhost.com
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    goto loop
)
your_command
```

**Remark:** If you want to use it every time the host is online, you can use the crontab on Linux or the Task Scheduler on Windows. If you want to run it every time the host comes online, you need a proper monitoring software.

Comment: Nice solution. Even easier is to take advantage of conditional execution `ping yourhost.com && echo hi` will only run the command `echo hi` if the ping completed successfully.  See http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution and http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-execute.html